# .Net Core can't load hostpolicy.dll (HRESULT: 0x800700C1)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm in the middle of upgrading my project from .Net Core 2.2 to 3.1, but I've ran into some issues. At first, by starting via the command line, I got an error message that the hostpolicy.dll couldn't be found in the output folder. To fix that I installed `Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPolicy`, but now I'm getting this error message:

```
Failed to load the dll from [*path*\win-x86\hostpolicy.dll], HRESULT: 0x800700C1
An error occurred while loading required library hostpolicy.dll from [*path*\win-x86\]
```

I've seen some posts about changing the runtime identifiers so I've set mine to `win7-x86;win10-x64`, but that  didn't do anything for me . The `win7-x86` is there because it's crucial to my project that the output is 32 bit, otherwise one of the assemblies I'm using won't work at all. Right now I'm letting the project compile as a DLL so I can start via the CMD and get some more detailed error messages.

Here's some more info out of my .csproj:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win7-x86;win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <Platforms>x86</Platforms>
    <OutputType>library</OutputType>
    <TargetLatestRuntimePatch>true</TargetLatestRuntimePatch>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And out of my .pubxml:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>x86</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <publishUrl>bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\x86\publish\</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <_IsPortable>false</_IsPortable>
    <PublishSingleFile>False</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishTrimmed>False</PublishTrimmed>
    <PublishReadyToRun>False</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

My runtimeconfig looks like this atm:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
"tfm": "netcoreapp3.1",
"includedFrameworks": [
  {
    "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
    "version": "3.1.0"
  },
  {
    "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
    "version": "3.1.0"
  }
],
"configProperties": {
  "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since getting the error, what have you tried?

Comment: Changing the runtime identifiers, trying different publish options (now I only have the deletion of old files checked), and at some point I also added "emitEntryPoint": true to my appsettings since I'm using MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may not be a particularly nice solution, I got it fixed by just creating a new project with .Net Core 3.1 and importing all the same files. Made some slight changes to the Startup.cs and Program.cs from the template to fit my needs and now it’s working again.